# Product Rating Filter for Layered Navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, filter, ratings

how to implement product rating filter in Layered Navigation? I can't found any tutorial for that..If you have any idea about it then share a link of tutorial or Free Extention.

Comment: Share Your Ideas Guys its Very urgent for me..

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial explains how create a custom filter in Layered Navigation: http://www.techytalk.info/create-custom-layered-navigation-filter-magento/

The `apply` and `getCount` are the main methods to be implemented in different way by tutorial. Basically you have to create a select from the ratings table and their respective conditions.

There is a paid extension too: http://www.manadev.com/rating-in-stock-out-of-stock-filter-in-layered-navigation

Comment: Thanks Denis..I already Downloaded tutorial which you mentioned above. 
Now I am Implementing..lets see what result will be coming and then i get back to you :) .

Comment: Denis Can Help For Rating Filter??
i tried bt not Working :(

Comment: I'll try do it on weekend and I feedback you.

Comment: Denis Will you tried??

Comment: Parth ! did you do product rating layered navigation ?